# How to find a leaf node in a binary NOT SORTED tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I want to find a leaf node in an unsorted binary tree and be able to use it in other functions.
i have this as an idea

UPDATED****

```
node * leaf(node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        return root;
    else
    {   leaf(root->left);
        leaf(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know recursion ? Have you gon through Binary tree theory ?

Comment: Show us your code. We are not here to do your homeworks

Comment: learn - http://geeksquiz.com/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

Comment: Check this code that will surely help you. http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/insert-delete-node-binary-search-tree-2843.aspx

Comment: this is a bst, its sorted. I have already done this. I am not sure about my recursion when i look up on the non sorted tree though.

Comment: where do i actually say it is sorted... the title was binary tree. In the description it says, the tree is not sorted. I replied on the link @SridharDD gave me. It is about a sorted binary tree, not the one im looking for.

Comment: I don't get your point. Do you mean you want to find the parent node of a leaf node, since you want to delete that leaf node?

Comment: I want to find a leaf node in an unsorted binary tree and be able to use it in other functions.

Comment: Now "I want to find a leaf node in an unsorted binary tree and be able to use it in other functions." should be the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If root has no children, then root is leaf node.

If root has left child, then the left child must have a leaf node.
Same as right child.

```
node* leaf(node* root) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        return root;
    } else if(root->left != NULL) {
        return leaf(root->left);
    } else {
        return leaf(root->right);
    }
}
```